# Spring Security 4 with custom authentication and local database

Tags: spring-security

Spring Security 4 enables developers to write less code, but sometimes this also causes thing easily to get out of control. For example, now I am writing a login function, once the user pressed a button (login/unionauth URI), an OAuth 2.0 like authentication offered by a 3rd party would be launched, and finally the result comes back and we compare the user with our local database. In order to do so, first I have adapter class like this:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }
```

Then I have `ssoFilter()` like this:

```java
public class UnionAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        // authentication steps.
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("tom", "N/A", null);
        AuthenticationManager manager = this.getAuthenticationManager();
        return manager.authenticate(token);
    }
```

Now, the problem is, manager is `null`. Why it is `null`? I think in case of password username mode, the `auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);` in adapter would enable a DAO manager. In [official website](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual), it has this:

> How to Add a Local User Database
>
> Many applications need to hold data about their users locally, even if
>   authentication is delegated to an external provider. We don’t show the
>   code here, but it is easy to do in two steps.
>
> 1. Choose a backend for your database, and set up some repositories (e.g.
>      using Spring Data) for a custom `User` object that suits your needs and
>      can be populated, fully or partially, from the external
>      authentication.
> 2. Provision a `User` object for each unique user that logs in by
>      inspecting the repository in your `/user` endpoint. If there is already
>      a user with the identity of the current `Principal`, it can be updated,
>      otherwise created.
>
> Hint: add a field in the `User` object to link to a unique identifier in
>   the external provider (not the user’s name, but something that is
>   unique to the account in the external provider).

Any idea how to add database into Spring Security OAuth2 or why the manager in the first paragraph is `null`?

Comment: You never call the setter for `AuthenticationManager` of `UnionAuthenticationProcessingFilter `. Why shouldn't it be `null`? Show us the implementation of `ssoFilter()` method.

Comment: @dur ssoFilter() returns an object of UnionAuthenticationProcessingFilter, and based on the comments configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth), and the comments of auth.userDetailsService, I think that is the place of setting AuthenticatinoManager, isn't it?

Comment: you are right, now after auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService); I get a daoauthenticationmanger from spring, and add this in customized filter by using setter. I didn't know configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) is called before ssoFilter().